# Can we use Google maps android api to transfer latlng to JavaScript api?

Tags: javascript, java, web-services, google-maps, rest

I want to use the latlng coordinates of android in in a web page in JavaScript latlng variable. Can we transfer them using Google maps api call?

I'm trying make android phone tracking app which shows the movement of phone in a web page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Track Page</title>
<style>
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=(I pasted my API key here)&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
    <script>
    var http;
    var url;
    var marker;
    var user_lat,user_lng;
    var map;
    var m;
    function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: {lat:17.37, lng: 82.50},
                zoom: 8
                });
    }

    setInterval(function(){main();},3000);
    function main() {
    http=new XMLHttpRequest();
    url="jsontext.txt";
    http.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(http.readyState==4 && http.status==200){
        var coordinates=JSON.parse(http.responseText);
        user_lat=coordinates.latitude;
        user_lng=coordinates.longitude;
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            draggable:true,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        label:'prasad',
            position: {lat: user_lat, lng: user_lng}
        });
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(user_lat,user_lng));
        marker.addListener('click', toggleBounce);
        }
    }
    http.open("POST",url,true);
    http.send();
    }
    function toggleBounce() {
    if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
        marker.setAnimation(null);
    }else {
        marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
    }
    }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my service which is incomplete. I'm struck not knowing how to send the values to the page.That is the reason why I left the method alone. If you can give me any inputs so that web service can send the variables to the webpage as soon as it receives them from URL, I will implement them and will work on it.

```
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;

@Path("/values")
public class Parameters {

    @POST
    @Path("/{param1}/{param2}")
    public void makeFile(@PathParam("param1")double a,@PathParam("param2")double b){

    }
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking.  Google Maps API calls can only manipulate the map in the Android app, and have no functionality to communicate with websites.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to create functionality on the website to receive locations for devices and store them, and then display them when the website is viewed.  I assume you would also need to have login functionality on the website, otherwise the location for anyone who has the app would be visible to everyone, which I assume is not desirable.  The app for this wouldn't be too hard to do, but the server side and web development would be a large project.

Comment: @Daniel Nugent I already made the android app. I also made a page which would display the location marker in desired location. I made the web service which could receive the latlng. What I'm thinking is, I'm not knowing how to send the variables in service to the variable in JavaScript. Can you help me in this regard?

Comment: If you already have the app written and successfully storing locations on your server, this isn't really an Android question.  Not sure if I can help, but if you add more details about exactly how you're stuck and show the code you have that isn't working, it would increase your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: @DanielNugent are you there